# Getting Error on Bar 0; array size is too large, maximum size is 100000

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Pine script displays error on bar 0, array size is too large; maximum size is 100000
my code is here
using nested for loop here help to resolve nested loops

```
   //@version=5
indicator("My script",max_bars_back = 55)
import E5Trading/E5TradingLibrary/1 as auto
import kaigouthro/into/2 as boof

price=hlc3
srce1=1
srce2=2
srce3=3
srce4=5
srce5=8
srce6=13
srce7=21
srce8=34
srce90=55
srce10=84
srce11=139

basis =ta.sma(price,srce1)
basis2 =ta.sma(price,srce2)
basisA =ta.sma(price,srce3)
basis2A =ta.sma(price,srce4)
basisB =ta.sma(price,srce5)
basis2B =ta.sma(price,srce6)
basisC =ta.sma(price,srce7)
basis2C =ta.sma(price,srce8)
basisD =ta.sma(price,srce90)
basis2D =ta.sma(price,srce10)
basisE =ta.sma(price,srce11)
```

arrsig=array.from(basis,basis2,basisA,basis2A,basisB,basis2B,basisC,basis2C,basisD,basis2D,basisE)
N=array.size(arrsig) - 1
funcml(data) =>

```
    grarry=array.new_float(0)
    rdarry=array.new_float(0)
    for i = 0 to N by 1
        for j = 0 to N by 1
            while i!=j        
                 
                gchk=auto.isReversalUpTrend(array.get(data,i),array.get(data,j))
                grchkv=boof.f(gchk)
                array.push(grarry,grchkv)
                 
                 
                rchk=auto.isReversalDownTrend(array.get(data,i),array.get(data,j))
                rdchkv=boof.f(rchk)
                array.push(rdarry,rdchkv)
            if j==N
                break
        
    [grarry,rdarry]
                 

                
[smacumgr,smacumrd]=funcml(arrsig)
cumresgr=array.sum(smacumgr)
cumresrd=array.sum(smacumrd)
vuptrnd=cumresgr>math.abs(cumresrd)
vdwntrnd=cumresgr<math.abs(cumresrd)

plotchar(vuptrnd,char="",color=color.green,location = location.top,size = size.tiny)
plotchar(vdwntrnd,char="",color=color.red,location = location.top,size=size.tiny)

//end

Please help
```

Comment: yes; but the script not working as expected; its the problem of the library im using i think; the isReversalDownTrend function returns all zero; i have to find another way; as im new im troubling

Comment: do you still have the error in your question ? 'Getting Error on Bar 0; array size is too large, maximum size is 100000' ?

Comment: No error now; but script not  working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is your while command in the nested loop that create an infinite array.
I think you wanted to test like this :

```
for i = 0 to N by 1
    for j = 0 to N by 1
        if i!=j        
            gchk=auto.isReversalUpTrend(array.get(data,i),array.get(data,j))
            grchkv=boof.f(gchk)
            array.push(grarry,grchkv)
          
            rchk=auto.isReversalDownTrend(array.get(data,i),array.get(data,j))
            rdchkv=boof.f(rchk)
            array.push(rdarry,rdchkv)
        else
            break
```